# Good MP3 or OGG Decoder written in C

Tags: c, audio, mp3, ogg, decoder

Hey, I was looking for a good MP3 or OGG decoder that use the BSD license or public domain and that is also light-weight (*something that comes with sources without the need of platform specific configuration*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not likely to find one for mp3 as there are a handful of [licensing issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing_and_patent_issues).

OGG is simply a container format that can hold audio, video, and more. Perhaps you mean ogg vorbis. Check out [stb_vorbis](http://nothings.org/stb_vorbis/). It's a free, public-domain C vorbis codec.

Comment: Can it decode to 16-bit stereo PCM? If so, tell me what function to use.

Comment: @Tamir: I linked the site.  I am not familiar with this product. You'll have to look at the information.

Comment: Why would libmad which is GPL not be persecuted into extinction, but a BSD licensed version be?

Comment: Update: the MP3 technology became patent-free in the United States on 16 April 2017 when U.S. Patent 6,009,399, held by and administered by Technicolor, expired.

https://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/ff/amm/prod/audiocodec/audiocodecs/mp3.html

Answer (score 2):

Like [this](http://nothings.org/stb_vorbis/) one?

Answer (score 2):

The [Xiph.org libvorbis](http://xiph.org/vorbis/) is available in pretty much every distro, and satisfies your requirement for a BSD-3-Clause license. "Light" is always relative... Also from Xiph.org available is libtremor, a integer-only vorbis decoder.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, there are Vorbis decoders. The [Fluendo MP3 decoder](http://www.fluendo.com/shop/product/fluendo-mp3-decoder/) is MIT (simplified BSD) licensed.